# image placement using hfill

Tags: diagrams, texmaker

Is it possible places images at the same horizontal level?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale=0.54]{/h.jpg}
\caption{Architecture}
\label{fig:Architecture}\hfill
\includegraphics[scale=0.54]{H.jpg}
\caption{Architecture}
\label{fig:Architecture}
\end{figure}
```

When I try doing this, all the images go to the last page.. no clue what's going on. i'm using TexMaker.

```
username ~ % identify H.jpg 
H.jpg JPEG 668x449 668x449+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 32.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
username ~ % identify h.jpg 
h.jpg JPEG 692x433 692x433+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 38.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: By "horizontal level", are you referring to "horizontal alignment"? How big are your images (place each `\includegraphics` inside an `\fbox` to get an idea of the size)? It could be that they're too big, and the figure is pushed to a page of floats.

Comment: Yes, I meant horizontal alignment. 
It really does not matter how big the images are, you can scale it down.

Comment: Could you include a graphic (draw it in MS Paint if you must...) of the intended output?

Comment: using `[h]` increases the chance the figure goes to the end of the document as it prevents top bottom and page floats (actually latex will give a warning and change that to `[ht]` just to give itself a chance to position the figure. The caption is forcing a paragraph break if you go `\includegraphics{a}\includegraphics{b}` they come side by side.

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in the following question: [Side by side images problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20799/5764)